# How to handle cookies using request method Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, cookies

I'm new to Node.Js, and I have written two methods post and get. First of all I want the post to look like the get request (asynchronous function) so I can export it from a different js file, but I'm not sure if it is asynchronous right now. Second, I want the get request to be able to send a cookie with the url also.

here is the scenario:
1- send a post request and set the cookie. The server will direct me to another location.
2- get the location and send a get request and include the cookie.

here is my code for POST:

```
request.post({
headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
url: 'http://example/login',
body: 'mes=heydude',
followRedirect: true,
form: {
  username: 'usr',
  password: 'pass'
}

}, function (error, response, body) {
if (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
var  setCookie = response.headers['set-cookie']
console.log('login success')
console.log(body)
})
```

This method works fine but how to make it an asynchronous function? like the below get request? also how to make the get request returns the cookie and the html?

```
function fetch (url, callback) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
request(url, function (error, response, html) {
  if (error) {
    return reject(error)
  }
  if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
    return reject(new Error('error code'))
  }
  return resolve(html)
  })
  })
}
```

If there is ane module that can do that on NPM let me know thanks.
Help a newbie and get a trophy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Express, you should look at [cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser). This is a library that handles cookies (as the name suggests) so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

If you don't know what [Express](https://expressjs.com/) is, I suggest you to look at it.

> Express is a minimal and flexible Node.js web application framework
>   that provides a robust set of features for web and mobile
>   applications.